# Using several ifelse statements with rasters

Tags: r

I want to apply different slightly equations to the same 2 raster files depending on the original conditions of y and x:

1. if y is positive and x is negative: atan2(y,x)*180/pi
2. if y is negative and x is negative, atan2(y,x)*180/pi + 90
3. if y is negative and x is negative, atan2(y,x)*180/pi + 180
4. if y is positive and x is negative, atan2(y,x)*180/pi + 270

I've tried grouping multiple ifelse statements into a function:

```
y <- raster(y) #formal raster class layer
x <- raster(x) #formal raster class layer

quad <- if(y>0 & x>0){
    (atan2(y,x)*180/pi)
}else{
    if(y<0 & x>0)
    ((atan2(y,x)*180/pi) +90)
}else{
    if(y<0 & x>0)
    ((atan2(y, x)*180/pi) +180)
}else{
    if (y>0 & x<0)
    ((atan2(y,x)*180/pi) +270)
```

Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
Error: unexpected 'else' in:
"        ((atan2(y,x)*180/pi) +90)
}else"

It doesn't create a new object either.

Comment: yes, you are right.. this was a mistake!

Answer (score 1):

Always include some example data

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
x <- setValues(r, sample(-180:180,ncell(r),replace=T))
y <- setValues(r, sample(-90:90,ncell(r),replace=T))
```

A general approach to problems like this is to write a function, test it, and use it with `calc` or `overlay`

```
fq <- function(x, y) {
    ifelse(y>0 & x>0, atan2(y,x)*180/pi, 
        ifelse(y<0 & x>0, atan2(y,x)*180/pi +90, 
        ifelse(y<0 & x<0, atan2(y,x)*180/pi +180,
        atan2(y,x)*180/pi +270)))
}

q <- overlay(x, y, fun=fq)
```

Another, more concise, way to write it

```
fq2 <- function(x, y) {
    z <- ifelse(y>0, ifelse(x>0, 0, 270), ifelse(x>0, 90, 180))
    atan2(y, x) * 180/pi + z
}
q2 <- overlay(x, y, fun=fq2)
```

Or like this

```
fz <- function(x, y) {
    z <- ifelse(y>0, ifelse(x>0, 0, 270), ifelse(x>0,90, 180))
}
z <- overlay(x, y, fun=fz)
q3 <- atan2(y, x) * (180/pi) + z
```

Or with the hidden *not yet supported* `raster:::.ifel` method

```
zz <- raster:::.ifel(y>0, raster:::.ifel(x>0, 0, 270), raster:::.ifel(x>0,90, 180))
q4 <- atan2(y, x) * (180/pi) + zz
```